# Salesforce Lightning Component Passing v.RecordID always null

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am a little new to Lightning Component so sorry for any confusion in my post.

I am trying to use a Lightning Component that resides in a Utility Bar. This Lightning component starts a Visual flow and it's supposed to pass in the current Record ID. IF there is no record ID it can send an empty string. But when I try to pass in {!v.RecordID} I get an Error:

```
We can't launch this flow because of a variable error. Send this error message to your admin. The value null is being provided for variable recordId but isn't compatible with the variable's data type (String). Check the places where you implemented the flow ‒ such as through a Lightning page or a custom button ‒ and make sure that all provided values are compatible with the variables' data types.
```

Here is my code for Component and Controller:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
  Account Id is {!v.recordId}  // TO BE noted, this {!v.REcordID} works just fine, it's just not passing the value back to the controller for some reason. 
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    init : function (component) {
       
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
      
       var inputVariables = [
            {
                name    : "recordId",
                type    : "String",
                value   : component.get("{!v.recordId}")
            }
        ];
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
        flow.startFlow("One_Click_Request_Flow_1",
                     inputVariables );
    },
})
```

---

```
({
    onRecordIdChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newRecordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(newRecordId);
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{!...}` is only used in the template/markup. You do not use it in JavaScript. So, your code should be:

```
value   : component.get("v.recordId")
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I am still getting the same error after replacing the component code with your suggestion.
'The value null is being provided for variable recordId but isn't compatible with the variable's data type (String).'

Comment: @SimpleCode Just realized you're using a Utility Bar component. As it happens, the value may be null during `aura:valueInit`; this is a race condition problem. Use the handler described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_lightning_utility_bar_page_context.htm), namely `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.recordId}" action="{!c.onRecordIdChange}"/>`

Comment: That worked Thanks! but I have a small issue here. So it works fine as long as there is a recordID, when there isn't for example if the user tries to launch this from the home screen, it gives them the error. is there a way to make the handler set the ID to '123' or something and pass it along? The flow I have is set to handle the ID if it's null o9r actual IDs so I want to be able to launch this from anywhere in salesforce with or without ID. Please let me know thanks!

Comment: @SimpleCode You just use an IF statement: `const recordId = component.get("v.recordId"); const inputs = []; if(recordId) inputs.push([{name:"recordId",type:"String",value:recordId}]);`

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox 
I dont mean to be a bother but I am having an issue with this, the IF statement works when there is no ID, once there is an ID the process breaks and I get the Error:
components/flowruntime/flowRuntimeV2.js:305:34

Comment: @SimpleCode You're welcome. Made a typo in my code, though, you shouldn't push an array. Still, if you got it working, that's what matters.

Comment: yes I am getting an error on that I Think, whats the fix for that sorry I have never coded JS before

Comment: @SimpleCode `const recordId = component.get("v.recordId"); const inputs = []; if(recordId) inputs.push({name:"recordId",type:"String",value:recordId});`

Comment: sorry one more issue here. When switching from the home screen to record, its not refresh the recordID it's always null, then switching from Account to home screen the ID  stays. any way we can ask for a refreshed ID on each load?